# How to pass array instead of required string NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

Script logic - script receives data from [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) > Then I have aggregation `$avg` to calculate the average of one asset. I will have more than one collection so I need to calculate average of every asset.

I have an array where I store collection names for MongoDB.

```
const symbols = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC", "AIONBTC"]
```

And I want to calculate average from MongoDB collection.

```
const collection = db.collection(symbols);
```

Here - `symbols` doesn't work for me, but if I simply add `"ADABTC"` then it works, but it doesn't fixes my problem since I want to use different collection names one after another one.

How I can pass an array if it's required to be a string? I need to use more than 1 collection names.

**FULL CODE**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://username:password@serveripadress:port/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const symbols = ["ADABTC", "AEBTC", "AIONBTC"]
    // Database Name
const dbName = 'Crypto';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    simplePipeline(db, function() {
        client.close();
    });
});

function simplePipeline(db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection(symbols);
    collection.aggregate(
        [{
            '$group': {
                _id: null,
                'Volume': {
                    '$avg': '$Volume'
                }
            }
        }],
        function(err, cursor) {
            assert.equal(err, null);

            cursor.toArray(function(err, documents) {
                console.log(documents)
                callback(documents);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pass an array into a function that is asking for a string. In your case what you need to do is `join` three collections. If you need to aggregate across multiple collections you can use the `$lookup` aggregation pipeline operator. You can connect using the first collection:

`db.collection(symbols)` => `db.collection(symbols[0])`

Then modify your query to join the three collections:

```
// Join with AEBTC collection
{
    $lookup:{
        from: symbols[1],       
        localField: //name of a value in first collection   
        foreignField: //name of same value in second collection
        as: //what you want to call it in the second table       
    }
},
{   $unwind: //what you called it },

// Join with AIONBTC collection
{
    $lookup:{
        from: symbols[2], 
        localField: //name of value in joined collections 1 and 2 
        foreignField: //name of that value in collection 3,
        as: //whatever you want to call it in the joined collection
    }
},
{   $unwind: //what you called it },

// define some conditions here 
{
    $match {}
},

// define which fields are you want to fetch
{   
    $group: {
            _id: null,
            'Volume': {
                '$avg': '$Volume'
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! But what if I will have more than 500 collections? It's going to be a mess of so many code

Comment: If you need to aggregate across 500 collections you may want to rethink your schemas